# Parameterized query with %

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, select, parameterized

I have a select statement

```
command.commandText = "SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM MYTABLE" +
                      " WHERE STATE LIKE @STATE + '%';";
```

This gives me an "'" error

I tried this one

```
command.commandText = "SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM MYTABLE" +
                      " WHERE STATE LIKE @STATE" + "'%';";
```

This gives me '%' error... What is the correct way

Comment: a small advice: never use string concatenation in sql queries ;)

Comment: sure thing MUG4N... what are other options

Comment: figured that one out sir... thank you

Comment: see Burgos post: use the Parameter class!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must add % in actual parameter value, not in query:

```
command.commandText = "SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM MYTABLE WHERE STATE LIKE @STATE";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("STATE", "CALI%");
```

If you have some value saved in string `valState`, for example, just append `%` in `AddWithValue`:

```
string valState = "Cali";
// ...
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("STATE", valState + "%");
```

Comment: Thanks Burgos... STATE is a parameter... I cannot hardcode that

Comment: Updated answer should do a trick, if I understand what you are asking. If not, can you update your question?

Comment: No problems! Glad that I've helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `%` in the string you are binding instead

```
stateStr += "%";
```

Then bind `stateStr`

Comment: Thanks Shredder... but the value of STATE comes as a parameter, so I don't want to hardcode

Comment: So you can append "%" to the state parameter like I did in my edit. Or append it in the actual bind statement like Burgos did in his edit. Is that what you mean?